# Spark aggregateByKey on Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

[Here](http://codingjunkie.net/spark-agr-by-key/)'s an example of aggregateByKey on mutable.HashSet[String] written by @[bbejeck](https://disqus.com/by/bbejeck/)

```
val initialSet = mutable.HashSet.empty[String]
val addToSet = (s: mutable.HashSet[String], v: String) => s += v
val mergePartitionSets = (p1: mutable.HashSet[String], p2: mutable.HashSet[String]) => p1 ++= p2
val uniqueByKey = kv.aggregateByKey(initialSet)(addToSet, mergePartitionSets)
```

But when I changed to Dataset, I got the following error, is that because Spark 2.0(the version I'm using) doesn't support aggregateByKey on Dataset?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.schema(Dataset.scala:393)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:486)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:495)
```

Here's the code:

```
case class Food(name: String,
                price: String,
                e_date: String)    
rdd.aggregateByKey( Seq(Food("", "", "")).toDS )( 
                    (f1,f2) => f1.union(f2), 
                    (f1,f2) => f1.union(f2))
/////////
found f1 = Invalid tree; null:
                    null
```

Any ideas why this is happening, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think aggregateByKey works with rdd only.
here is the documentation (it's for python)
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html

Remove .toDS and try the code.
Maybe convert it into DS after the aggregation is done (not sure if it would be any better in performance).